# Adding mysql data and numericupdown.value in same row VB NET

Tags: vb.net, listview, numericupdown

so i got this problem. I got 2 listviews, the first one shows the results from the database. And the second one is the "Shopping cart".

What i want is the second listview too also add the amount chosen, from the numericupdown.value in the same ROW. At the time i get the amount in 1 row, and the data from the database in the second row.

Any help is much appreciated!

Code:

```
Public Sub Button6_click(sender as object, e as eventargs) Handles button6.click

    Dim lvi as new ListViewItem

    If listview1.selecteditems.count > 0 then
      lvi = listview1.selecteditems(0)
      Dim lvi2 As New ListViewItem
      Dim amount As Integer = CInt(numericupdown1.value)

      lvi2 = CType(lvi.clone, ListViewItem)
      listview2.items.add(amount)
      listview2.items.add(lvi2)
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: So, what is the question?  Is there a problem with the code there?  What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: The problem is that i cant put both the numericupdown.value AND the liv.clone in the SAME row.

Comment: The LV is such a miserable control for DB ops.  You need to add the amount as a sub item

Comment: What would you prefer to use instead of LV? Im not a very novice programmer.

Comment: the DataGridView is specifically made for DB ops, no rows to make, no columns to make, hardly anything at all to do

Comment: Ok thx alot! I will take a look at datagridview instead then. And also thank you for guiding me into adding the amount as an subitem.